# How do you set a setting value to null in bareos?

Tags: bacula, bareos

I keep getting this error, and I think it's because my JobDef contains a default schedule:

```
31-Jan 23:30 bareOSdirector JobId 67: Error: Bareos bareOSdirector 16.2.4 (01Jul16):
  Build OS:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu debian Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)
  JobId:                  67
  Job:                    RestoreFiles.2017-01-31_23.30.32_23
  Restore Client:         bareOSdirector-fd
  Start time:             31-Jan-2017 23:30:52
  End time:               31-Jan-2017 23:30:52
  Elapsed time:           0 secs
  Files Expected:         0
  Files Restored:         0
  Bytes Restored:         0
  Rate:                   0.0 KB/s
  FD Errors:              2
  FD termination status:  
  SD termination status:  
  FD  Secure Erase Cmd:   <NULL>
  SD  Secure Erase Cmd:   <NULL>
  Termination:            *** Restore Error ***
```

If I want to keep the default value of which schedule to use in my JobDef,  what value do I need to override the `RestoreFiles` job's `Schedule` with, to prevent it from being run?

```
JobDefs {
  Name = "DefaultJob"
  Type = Backup
  Level = Incremental
  Messages = "standard"
  Storage = "bareOSdirector_FileStorage"
  Pool = "Daily"
  FullBackupPool = "Full"
  IncrementalBackupPool = "Incremental"
  DifferentialBackupPool = "Differential"
  FileSet = "SelfTest"
  Schedule = "WeeklyCycle"
  JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
  WriteBootstrap = "/var/lib/bareos/%c.bsr"
}

Job {
  Name = "RestoreFiles"
  Type = Restore
  Messages = "standard"
  Storage = "bareOSdirector_FileStorage"
  Pool = "Incremental"
  Client = "bareOSdirector-fd"
  FileSet = "LinuxAll"
  JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
  Where = "/tmp/bareos-restores"
  Schedule = ????
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to skip over the `RestoreFiles` (disable it) by setting `Enabled = "no"` in the Job, it no longer appears in the schedule after I do that.